# install ruby 2.3.1 - Ubuntu 19.10 - Build Failed

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I am new to Ubuntu and Ruby installation, and Linux installation in general.

I'm getting the below output when i try to install Ruby 2.3.1 via rbenv. Any idea what the issue could be? Many thanks.

```
prem@chinz:~$ rbenv install 2.3.1
Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.1...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 19.10 using ruby-build 20191124-2-g77e949a)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20191205111801.21317.gjqU1A
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20191205111801.21317.log

Last 10 log lines:
make[1]: *** [exts.mk:208: ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
linking shared-object objspace.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20191205111801.21317.gjqU1A/ruby-2.3.1/ext/objspace'
linking shared-object date_core.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20191205111801.21317.gjqU1A/ruby-2.3.1/ext/date'
linking shared-object nkf.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20191205111801.21317.gjqU1A/ruby-2.3.1/ext/nkf'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20191205111801.21317.gjqU1A/ruby-2.3.1'
make: *** [uncommon.mk:203: build-ext] Error 2
```

Comment: Note: when i run the same command to install ruby version 2.5.5, it installs successfully, however I need to install version 2.3.1 as the project I'm working on uses this version

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need an older version of open ssl. Check this link https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#openssl-usrincludeopensslasn1_mach102-error-error-this-file-is-obsolete-please-update-your-software